# max number of allowable warnings while compiling

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

Is it possible to 'tell' compiler that if total number of warnings (while compiling a C++ program) are more than say 10 then stop compiling further, and emit an error?
Or is it possible to hack a compiler like clang to provide this functionality.

Comment: Since clang is open source, it's of course possible to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this kind of feature in gcc or clang. You can certainly try to patch it into either of them, both are open source. There is also `-Werror` (accepted by both compilers) which simply treats warnings as errors.

Answer (score 3):

GCC has two options together would achieve this, from [gnu online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Werror
>       Make all warnings into errors.
>
> -fmax-errors=n 
>        Limits the maximum number of error messages to n, at which point GCC bails out rather than attempting to continue processing the source
>   code.

This would make a build with any warnings fail though, the options just define when to stop parsing.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `-Werror` to make warnings into errors and -`fmax-errors=n` to set the limit.
(Also, perhaps making your code completely warning free would be a good thing).